# PHP Using a Library via Composer To An Existing PHP App That Don't Use Composer

Tags: php, namespaces

I have an existing php app.  I would like to use this library: [Name Parser](https://packagist.org/packages/davidgorges/human-name-parser#1.0.0)
This library used composer.  I download the library via composer and copied the NameParser folder into my existing PHP App.

When I used it I got an error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "HumanNameParser\Name" ... /HumanNameParser/Parser.php:88

How I used the library in a .php file

```
<?php
  include_once('includes/HumanNameParser/Parser.php');
  $nameparser = new Parser();
?>
```

I'm pretty sure, I am messing this up.  I don't know the difference between namespace, use, include_once(), include(), require(), require_once().

Comment: `require './vendor/autoload.php';` should automatically include what you need, you don't need to include or require things yourself if they are installed by Composer.

Comment: If you're manually copying all of the files from the vendor folder to your non-Composer app, you need to `include_once` each of the classes which gets used, for example `include_once('includes/HumanNameParser/Name.php');` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `composer require davidgorges/human-name-parser`.

Then in your application:

`include_once('vendor/autoload.php');`

Then you'll be able to use it with:

```
new HumanNameParser\Parser\Parser();
```

You can add the autoloader to your entire application (where it bootstraps) or just to the file where you want to use the Parser package.